# Construct a new matrix with corresponding values of a max of multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have 3 matrices P1,P2,P3 that represent transition matrices and R1,R2,R3 that are reward matrices.

```
# Set up initial variables for Policy 1
P1 <- matrix(c(1/2, 1/4, 1/4,
               1/16,3/4,3/16,
               1/4,1/8,5/8), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE);rownames(P1)=c("1","2","3");P1
R1 <- matrix(c(10,4,8,
               8,2,4,
               4,6,4), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE);rownames(R1)=c("1","2","3");R1


# Set up initial variables for Policy 2
P2 <- matrix(c(1/2, 0, 1/2,
               1/16,7/8,1/16), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE);rownames(P2)=c("1","2");P2
R2 <- matrix(c(14,0,18,
               8,16,8), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE);rownames(R2)=c("1","2");R2



# Set up initial variables for Policy 3
P3 <- matrix(c(1/4,1/4,1/2,
               1/8,3/4,1/8,
               3/4,1/16,3/18), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE);rownames(P3)=c("1","2","3");P3
R3 <- matrix(c(10,2,8,
               6,4,2,
               4,0,8), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE);rownames(R3)=c("1","2","3");R3
```

Taking the maximum of the row sum of their each matrix multiplication, I take 3 values q1=8,q2=16,q3=7.

```
q1 <- max(unname(rowSums(P1*R1)))
q2 <- max(unname(rowSums(P2*R2)))
q3 <- max(unname(rowSums(P3*R3)))
```

I want to construct a new transition matrix that will have row elements corresponding to their max row multiplication of each matrix. For example 8 came from the maximum row sum of the first row of P1 times R1. 16 came from the first row of P2 times R2.

The matrix must be :

```
P_NEW = matrix(c(1/2,1/4,1/4,1/2,0,1/2,1/4,1/4,1/2),3,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
[2,] 0.50 0.00 0.50
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
```

How can I do it in R ?

Ideally how from this example the policy iteration and policy improvement can be done with MDPtoolbox package in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `max`, you can use `which.max` to extract the index:

```
q1 <- which.max(unname(rowSums(P1*R1)))
q2 <- which.max(unname(rowSums(P2*R2)))
q3 <- which.max(unname(rowSums(P3*R3)))

rbind(P1[q1,],P2[q2,],P3[q3,])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
[2,] 0.50 0.00 0.50
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
```